# Calculating distribution of the hiring problem

Tags: probability, random-variables

The problem:

Let $a_1,...,a_5$ be candidates for a job in some company, assume the company interviews one of them at a time, and their arrival for the interview is totally random, also assume a1 is the worst candidate and an is the best.

Let X be a random variable where that is equal to the number of candidates to get the hired, and $X_i$ to be an indicator for for $a_i$ to get hired or not.

I want to calculate $E[X],Var[X],Std[X]$,and $E[X_i],Var[X_i]Std[X_i]$.

I have worked out that

$Pr[X_i=1]=Pr[$the i'th candidate is the best among the first i candidates$]=\frac{1}{i}.$

$Pr[X=j]=Pr[$Exactly j candidates are hired$]=\sum_{i=1}^{5}{X_i}=j.$

I don't understand how to calculate the sum  to be j for $Pr[X=j]$, it would make it clear for me if I understood what is for example $Pr[X=3]=Pr[$for 3 candidates to get hired].

Comment: How does the company determine who to hire? Say they interview the candidates in the order $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$. Who gets a job? What's the general rule?

Comment: By that order every one gets hired. But let's say $a_5$ gets interviewed first then he gets hired after that if for example $a_3$ gets interviewed he wont get hired since $a_5$ is better

Comment: From this reference exactly in the top of the second page after the title https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~nam1/TA/HWSols/hw7sol.pdf .Is it correct to say that $Pr[X=j]=\frac{1}{j!}$?

Comment: That link doesn't really explain it either, but I think I can guess what the rule is supposed to be from the given solution. Basically you hire each person who is the best candidate seen up to that point. So for example you always hire the first person, you hire the second person exactly when they're better than the first person, etc.

Comment: Ah i see thank you.Lets say i have calculated the expectancy of $X$ to be $\sum_{i=1}^5 \frac{1}{i}$ how would i calculate the variance for example.(I have looked at the formula and did not understand how i should calculate it)